# Add property just for first div in a set of matches

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this HTML code and I can't change it or edit but I need to change how it looks like:

```
<form method="POST" id="go123pago">
    <div align="center" style="width:220px">
        <div style="float:left;padding:10px;width:190px">
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I need to set `padding: 30px 0 0 0` to `#go123pago` first div in this case the one with `220px`, how I can achieve this?

Comment: `form>div:first-of-type{}` or `form div[style="width:220px"] {} ` if this is the only one receiving this inline CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pure CSS you can use the [nth-of-type](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) selector, in your case, it would look something like this:

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" id="go123pago">
    <div align="center" style="width:220px">
        <div style="float:left;padding:10px;width:190px">
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
#go123pago:nth-of-type(1) {
    padding: 30px 0 0 0
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I saw you tagged jQuery so here is a solution using it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#go123pago div").css("padding",  "30px 0 0 0");
})
```

jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4cjgLy0r/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelector()` (JS function) to find the first matching element with the given CSS selector.

```
document.querySelector("div[style='width:220px']").style.padding = "30px 0 0 0";
```

but this would only work the style was exactly and only `width:220px`.

---

And now that I realize you have the [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) tag, you could do this easier with jQuery:

```
$("div[style='width:220px']").first().css("padding", "30px 0 0 0");
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @David Poirier's answer, using jQuery, the `.find()` method should work slightly faster according to the [jQuery docs](https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/).

```
// Super-fast:
$( "#go123pago" ).find('div').css("padding",  "30px 0 0 0");
```